# How to add a tag before another tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm developing a soccer website  and i want to add before hometeam a red card and after away team a red card,
This is my code:

```
 if (isHome) {
   $(dataRow).find(".homeTeamName").before("<span class='redcard'></span>");
 } else {
   $(dataRow).find(".AwayTeamName").after("<span class='redcard'></span>");
 }
```

i also used append() to add a tag but it didn't appear nothing
this is my css class:

```
.redcard {
    background-color:red;
    width:13px;
    height:20px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #888888;
    border-radius:3px
 }
```

Comment: Can you create an [MCVE] with html and more js to show what `dataRow` is

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for the `prepend()` function?

Comment: And what is the problem? pls show the html code too.

Comment: <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center">
                            <a  versus-id="@c.MatchID" data-toggle="tooltip" 
data-placement="top" style="cursor:pointer;"
                               title="@homeMLName - @awayMLName">
                                <span class="homeTeamName">@homeMLName</span> - <span 
  class="AwayTeamName">@awayMLName</span>
                            </a>

                        </td>
</tr>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like your javascript is correct. The reason why you are not seeing the spans is because they have no width, since they are inline elements.

Try with this CSS:

```
.redcard{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:red;
    width:13px;
    height:20px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #888888;
    border-radius:3px
}
```